# how to get output of printf inside the function to the main program in c

Tags: c

I have a function which print lot of `printf` statements, number of lines as output is not fixed. I need to get all the lines which are getting printed in `myFun` to the main function and used them for some other purpose. Can someone please guide how to do that ?

```
#include<stdio.h>


int myFun(char* name){
    printf("myFun: this is important line too\n");
    printf("myFun: my name is %s\n",name);
    printf("myFun: this is a important line needed in main, genrated from some function called inside myFun\n");
}

int main(){


    printf("this is main and now calling myFun\n");
    myFun("monk");

    //how can I get all the output of all three printf statements done inside myFun to the main function ?


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make a dynamically allocated array of strings and return the corresponding pointer.

Comment: Guy probably want `sprintf` and friends

Comment: Your function the way is designed is wrong. If there is no need of return statement use void.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try saving the strings into an array, and `return`ing the whole array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char **Func(char *name)
{
    int numOfOutputs = 3;
    numOfOutputs++; //Append an extra null byte to the end so we know when it ends
    int maximumStringSize = 100;
    char **final = (char **)malloc(numOfOutputs * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfOutputs; i++)
        final[i] = (char *)malloc(maximumStringSize * sizeof(char));

    strcpy(final[0], "myFun: this is important line too\n");
    sprintf(final[1], "myFun: my name is %s\n", name);
    strcpy(final[2], "myFun: this is a important line needed in main, genrated from some function called inside myFun\n");

    //Final member assigned as NULL to indicate end
    final[3] = NULL;
    return final;
}
int main()
{
    printf("this is main and now calling myFun\n");
    char **result = Func("monk");
    //Print result, check for ending member with the nullbyte we added
    for(int i = 0 ; result[i] != NULL; i++)
        printf("For i = %d, string is -> %s", i, result[i]);
    //Don't forget to free with something like this:
    for(int i = 0 ; result[i] != NULL; i++)
        free(result[i]);
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```